# Как округлить число до двух первых значащих цифр после запятой?

Tags: python

К своему стыду никак не могу найти способ округлять числа так (до двух первых значащих цифр после запятой):

```
0,0003658313517468447045911834644229 -> 0,00037
0.15 -> 0.15
0.156 -> 0.16
0.006 -> 0.006
0.0066 -> 0.0066
```

Есть способ делать это из коробки?

Comment: первый пример в вопросе противоречит описанию...

Comment: 1 - из коробки такой функции нет. 2 - нужно округление для вывода (результат - строка) или округление как числа (результат - float)?

Comment: @insolor нужен float, спасибо

Comment: Нашел такой вариант: round_to_n = lambda x, n: round(x, -int(floor(log10(x))) + (n - 1)). Уточняю у заказчика, правильные ли цифры он получает

Comment: @MaxU да и последние два

Comment: 0 после запятой - тоже значащая цифра!

Comment: @IvanBlohin ваша формула будет работать только для чисел от -1 до 1. Иначе "целая часть" войдёт в "значащие цифры". Т.е. 1.003 округлится до 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня получилась такая функция:

```
import math

def round_to(num, digits=2):
    if num == 0: return 0
    scale = int(-math.floor(math.log10(abs(num - int(num))))) + digits - 1
    if scale < digits: scale = digits
    return round(num, scale)

# ну или оно же в виде однострочной лямбды
_round_to = lambda num, digits: 0 if num == 0 else round(num, max(int(-math.floor(math.log10(abs(num - int(num))))) + digits - 1, digits))


nums = [0.0003658313517468447045911834644229, 0.15, 0.156, 0.006, 0.0066]
print(*[(x, round_to(x)) for x in nums], sep="\n")
```

Результат:

```
(0.0003658313517468447, 0.00037)
(0.15, 0.15)
(0.156, 0.16)
(0.006, 0.006)
(0.0066, 0.0066)
```

Comment: Можно сократить строчку с `if`, если взять `scale = max(int..., digits)`

Comment: @CrazyElf ... ну и тогда уж сразу вставить это в `round(num, ...)`.

Comment: Наверное )  Рефакторинг нельзя закончить, его можно только прекратить! )

Comment: @CrazyElf Прекратил, доведя до одной строки. )